# Check string for an array match item and keep checking

Tags: javascript

I want to store some strings and check, if strings from textarea are equal to stored one.

I decided to start with arrays.

```
var string = "something like this happens everyday in my life";

var array1 = [
    "thing",
    "something"
];

var array2 = [
    "happens",
    "life"
];
```

I got it how it works with one word strings:

```
if(string.search(array1) != -1) {
    console.log("array1");
} 

if(!!~jQuery.inArray(string.search, array1)) {
    console.log("array1");
}
```

But what i need is to compare every item of this sentence to my arrays and get every match.  Even if there is several matches in one array. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check whether a string contains a given substring is with [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var s = "Hello, how are you today? Is everything alright?"
// if you want the search to be case insensitive:
// s = s.toLowerCase();
var myWords = ["how", "everything"];
for (var i = 0; i < myWords.length; i++) {
    var pos = s.indexOf(myWords[i]);
    if (pos == -1) {
        console.log("word", myWords[i], "not found.");
    } else {
        console.log("word", myWords[i], "found at position", i);
    }
}
```

If you want to store all the matches, you could have a

```
var matches = [];
```

and, under the `else` block, have `matches.push(myWords[i])`;

If you need to support `≤IE8`, then you can use the following function to search for a substring within a string:

```
var getPosition = function (s, word) {
    var len = s.length,
        wlen = word.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len - wlen + 1; i++) {
        if (s[i] == word[0] && s.slice(i, i + wlen) == word)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This can be useful, if you don't want to load an external library, i.e., jQuery or Polyfill, just for `indexOf`.

Comment: Note that `indexOf` does not work in some versions of internet explorer, hence jquery's alternative

Comment: @SLC I added an alternative to the jQuery function, in case the OP doesn't want to use any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For now i ended up using this for every array i have. I Ctrl C/V this 10 times, for every
for (var i = 0; i < **array**.length; i++) {

`for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    var pos = text.indexOf(states[i]);
    if (pos == -1) {
        console.log("word", states[i], "not found.");
    } else {
    $( '#log').append( "~STATE~" + "<br>");
    }
}`